# Cannot create adapted_frame from file

Tags: c++, webrtc

I'm trying to create one stream from file using webRTC. For that, I'm using filevideocapturer, calling with the following manner:

```
cricket::FileVideoCapturer capturer;
capturer.akeNativeCapturer().Init(filename);
```

I'm getting the following message from webRTC:

```
Error(webrtcvideoframefactory.cc:38): Failed to create WebRtcVideoFrame in CreateAliasedFrame.
```

and

```
Error(videocapturer.cc:562): Couldn't convert to I420 - 2 ! From 269488144x269488144x0.660066 To 269488144 x 269488144
```

The file I'm using is a HD .yuv video file.

Any ideas?